# Htaccess rewrite rules for this url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I just started to learn htaccess and i'd like to rewrite my current urls from this:

```
http://www.url.com/?location=script
```

To:

```
http://www.url.com/script
```

So far i've managed to do this but now i want to have a directory with more controllers so i can have something like this:

```
http://www.url.com/script/method
```

Structure: Script directory --> method.php

Currently my directory structure for includes its like this:

assets-->client(directory):

- login.php
- logout.php
- register.php
- something.php

And i'd like to access these using a url like:

```
    url.com/client/login
    url.com/client/logout
    url.com/client/register
    url.com/client/something
```

My .htaccess:

```
    <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?location=$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

PHP based inclusion code:

```
####################################################################
#                       PARSE THE CURRENT PAGE                     #
####################################################################

  $includeDir =".".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."assets/controllers".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $includeDefault = $includeDir."home.php"; 
    if(isset($_GET['ajaxpage']) && !empty($_GET['ajaxpage'])){
        $_GET['ajaxpage'] = str_replace("\0", '', $_GET['ajaxpage']);
        $includeFile =   basename(realpath($includeDir.$_GET['ajaxpage'].".php"));
        $includePath = $includeDir.$includeFile;
        if(!empty($includeFile) && file_exists($includePath)) {
            include($includePath);
        }
        else{
            include($includeDefault);
        }
        exit();
    } 

  if(isset($_GET['location']) && !empty($_GET['location']))
            {
                $_GET['location'] = str_replace("\0", '', $_GET['location']);
                $includeFile = basename(realpath($includeDir.$_GET['location'].".php"));
                $includePath = $includeDir.$includeFile;

                if(!empty($includeFile) && file_exists($includePath)) 
                {
                    include($includePath);
                }
                else 
                {
                    include($includeDefault);
                }

            } 
            else 
            {
                include($includeDefault);
            }
```

All my controllers are in assets/controllers/ucp/login.php for example.

Comment: Without answering your question, consider writing your PHP following the [PSR-2 guide](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md). Other PHP programmers might be more eager to help you out.

Comment: I will consider your advice in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/client/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)$
    RewriteRule ^[a-z]+ index.php?location=$2 [L]
</ifModule>
```

It does include a leading slash and doesn't have the PHP extension. But this can be altered in PHP to suit your needs.

Be wary though, your code gives access to all your PHP files. You might want to check $_GET['location'] against an array of allowed locations. Consider the following URL as example of how this could go wrong

```
http://example.com/index.php?location=../drop_database.php
```

Comment: Where do you get `$2` from?

Comment: Every included script its in assets/controllers directory and then i have another directory that contains the scripts. For example: assets/controllers/error/traceback.php. With your code the url: http://.../error/traceback its not working!. I've also changed /client/ with /assets/controllers/error/

Comment: @MikeRockett $2 is the second match from the regex. 'client' being the first.

Comment: @AndreiVlad If your code is 3 levels deep instead of 1 replace `$2` for `$4`. Try http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ . It parsed my htaccess as valid and working.

Comment: Can you provide some more information, like: what error are you getting? What does the URL I provided previous comment tell you?